# Why Apple allow to create multiple HMHomeManager instances

Tags: ios, homekit

I'll like to know why Apple allow to create more than one instance of HMHomeManager and what is the purpose of it?

I would expect the instance of HMHomeManager to be a singleton.

Answer (score 4):

I can't speak for Apple but I see no cases where `HMHomeManager` would benefit from being a singleton and several clear disadvantages.

1. `HMHomeManager` has a `delegate` property. The delegate pattern works well when you want a delegator to send messages to a single delegate or when many delegators might share a delegate. It is however not useful when one delegator might produce messages of interest to many delegates which would be the case if `HMHomeManager` were a singleton.
2. Singletons are not easily deallocated. Any app using a `HMHomeManager` as a singleton would keep that object in memory monitoring for changes to the home database even if it was no longer needed.
3. The assumption that there should only ever be one `HMHomeManager` may not hold true forever. While one `HMHomeManager` can contain many homes they all share a common user. Designing this class as a singleton would preclude an app from acting on behalf of multiple users at once. Even if there's never a need for such behavior developers might be wise to avoid selecting an interface which cannot support it early in the design process.

Comment: IMHO, it's still bad design. It does use a delegate, to your point (1), but it should probably use completion blocks rather than having a class with a delegate. This would make interacting with it much easier, as the homes property isn't valid until it calls the delegate, which is a pain. It could be implemented as an interface to the database using blocks and be much easier to interact with.

Answer (score 1):

Don't create multiple instances of HMHomeManager.May be below code will be helpful. If you want to made any changes to the existing home try to execute the code after made the changes like add room,zone...

```
for(HMHome *home in appDelegate.homeManager.homes)
{
    if([home.name isEqualToString:appDel.selectedHome.name])
    {
        appDel.selectedHome = home;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would expect internally there is a singleton client that communicates with the home daemon, the same way `CLLocationManager` has a singleton `CLLocationInternalClient.sharedServiceClient` which allows us to scatter location managers throughout our app without having to worry about forwarding notifications or multicasting delegate methods around ourselves. I haven't examined `HMHomeManager` as closely and it does seem quite a rushed API so maybe not as well designed. It's concerning the documentation mentions "the manager for your app" as if we are only supposed to have one. Furthermore when you receive the home changed delegate call it tells us to "invalidate your own app's objects that cache the home's data". One thing I have noticed is when you init a `HMHomeManager` it inits all the rooms, services and accessory objects which in my case is about 400KB (calculated by initing 10 home managers and comparing the RAM difference) for my 301 characteristics, 68 services, 19 accessories home (I used Allocations in Instruments searching for 'HM' to learn this). So we probably should stick to one manager per app but there is a serious design problem with the API that when we toggle a characteristic the delegate method isn't called so we need to reach out to our app's object and invalidate it rather than it happening automatically for us like any other API would.

[image: Instruments]